# Simplify same power multipliers

Tags: maxima

In Maxima, I can use "rootscontract" to combine multipliers with the same rational power:

```
(%i1) x^(1/2) * y^(1/2), rootscontract;
(%o1) sqrt(x*y)
```

Is there a standard method to combine multipliers for arbitrary powers?:

```
(%i2) 2^x * 3^x, some_option;
(%o2) 6^x
```

If "some_option" doesn't exist in the vanilla Maxima, how do I approach the the above simplification task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own function:

```
pow_divide (exp, pow):= ((exp)^(1/pow))^pow;
```

With :

```
pow_divide((2^x*3^x), x);
```

it gives you : 6^x